# Angular directive - offsetHeight outputs 0

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple popup directive, in there i need to find the height of a div.

When I output the div `console.log($elem.find('.reviews-slide-detail'))`, it shows me the full object, with `[0] -> offsetHeight` showing a number (223).

But when I try to output the number directly `console.log($elem.find('.reviews-slide-detail')[0].offsetHeight);`, it shows 0.

My div is not hidden, its fix positioned and very normal in styling.

Does anyone know any reason to this difference?

EDIT:

Part of the directive:

```
function resultReviewDirective($timeout, $http, $state, UtilService, ResultService, Session, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'modules/core/templates/result.review.html',           
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs){


            $scope.reviewFunc.setHeight = function() {


                console.log($elem.find('.reviews-slide-detail'));
                console.log($elem.find('.reviews-slide-detail')[0].offsetHeight);


            };

        }
    };
}


angular.module('core').directive('resultReview', resultReviewDirective);
```

Comment: It is because, you probably are trying to access the element too early. `console.log($elem.find('.detail'))` show you full object because console stores the object's reference which gets updates automatically when it renders, but when you output `console.log($elem.find('.detail')[0].offsetHeight)` directly it is no reference and just outputs the value at that time of logging.

Comment: Can you add the code for the directive?

Comment: @PSL, I am triggering the `console.log` with a click function, so its not triggered on page load, but I'm still getting the same issue, any ideas?

Comment: Wee pageload does not matter. :), angular runs digest cycle to update DOM with bindings and that happens after ng-click as well. Just to test it wrap it inside a $timeout and see

Comment: @PSL so should I use digest in this case?

Comment: @muudless no you dont, as i said wrap it in a timeout and see

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to PSL's comment, wrapping it in `$timeout` worked.